# How to do a reference of my UIViewController in the SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I need to have my UIViewController as a property of my GameScene.
So before calling presentScene, I set the property with the UIViewController.

My UIViewController class:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene:GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            // Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
            if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {

                self.scene=sceneNode

                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                sceneNode.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

                    sceneNode.gameViewController = self //SET THE PROPERTY
                    view.presentScene(sceneNode)

                    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                    view.showsPhysics = true
                    view.showsFPS = true
                   view.showsNodeCount = true    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My GameScene class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    var gameViewController:GameViewController!

    override func sceneDidLoad() {

         print(self.gameViewController) // -> CRASH
         //DO SOME STUFF
    }
}
```

I get this crash:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**EDIT 1**

So I tried to use:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.DeviceBounds.rawValue

    //ALL MY INIT CODE
}


override func sceneDidLoad() {
    super.sceneDidLoad()
    //NOTHING HERE
}
```

But the physic world doesn't work anymore. My crash disappears, but the physic world is broken.

In the console I have:

```
--->GameViewController - viewDidLoad()<---
--->GameScene - sceneDidLoad()<---
--->GameScene - sceneDidLoad()<---
--->GameScene - didMove(to:)<---
--->GameViewController - viewWillAppear<---
--->GameViewController - viewDidAppear<---
```

Comment: The real question is,  Why do you want to do this, and is this the best way to approach it.  By GameScene holding onto UIViewController, you are running the risk of your GameScecne and ViewController never being allowed to dealloc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sceneDidLoad` function gets called before you have set the reference to gameViewController. You should use the SKScene `didMoveToView` function instead.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    print(self.gameViewController)
}
```

You could set breakpoints in Xcode (in your gameScene and in gameViewController) and see the timing of events. As an aside, it is a better practice to implement the `delegate pattern` using protocols, rather than using concrete references like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to add to `GameViewController`, after this code:

```
// Get the SKScene from the loaded GKScene
            if let sceneNode = scene.rootNode as! GameScene? {
```

the line:

```
               sceneNode.gameViewController = self
```

Also, in your scene class you should use:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
```

because `sceneDidLoad()` method (now in iOS10) is the equivalent to `viewDidLoad()` in *UIKit*, **but your scene is not yet been presented by the view**.

Comment: Nope, the line is just before view.presentScene(sceneNode)

Comment: I followed your advice, but it happens something strange, as soon as I used override func didMove(to view: SKView), all the physics behavior doesn't work in my scene... I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you put in didMove also self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self and the other initializations related to your physicsWorld?

Comment: Check also how you create your physicsBodies, probably you have some issue about origins or sizes of your bodies related to the scene.

Comment: Ok I'm going to search, but why just in moving my code in didMove, my physics is broken? It worked perfectly in sceneDidLoad. I didn't change anything,  the coordinates system is the same.

Comment: Your phisics should work perfectly also in sceneDidLoad, have you called also super.sceneDidLoad() ?

Comment: @cmi What do you mean for "physic world is broken". Please be more specific so I can try to help you

Comment: Contacts and Collisions between my nodes don't work. Gravity is OK.

Comment: @cmi Your physics bodies are constructed on volume-based bodies or edge-based bodies? Have you try to change this one?

Comment: Both. My game area is constructed with a edge-based body. The ball inside, with volume-based body. My ball has to be bounce on the game area edge. If I copy my code in diMove, my ball doesn't bounce.

Comment: Seems a problem due to edgeLoopFrom size, try to set a breakpoint after it and check the size in the debug console : po <yourBoundaries>.size

Answer (score 0):

On GameSceneViewController use on ViewDid Load:

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
  currentGame = scene as! GameScene
  currentGame.gameViewController = self
 }
```

Then you will be able to have both with reference to each other.